# Rails query from three models using joins

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have the following models in my Rails application:

```
class Test
    has_many :tests_profiles
    has_many :class_profiles

class TestsProfile
    belongs_to :class_profile
    belongs_to :test

class ClassProfile
    has_many :tests_profiles
```

I must query `tests` belonging to particular `ClassProfile`. My present helper function is like this:

```
def get_tests(class_profile)
        return Test.joins(:tests_profiles).where(tests_profiles: {class_profile_id: class_profile.id})
```

In my `erb` file, I am looping through the result like this:

```
<% tests = get_tests(class_profile) %>
    <% tests.each do |test| %>
        <th><%= test.name %></th>
    <% end %>
```

But the problem here is I am getting all the tests names and not the only ones associated with that particular `ClassProfile`. How can I correct it so that it functions that way I want it to?

Comment: 'tests belonging to particular `ClassProfile`' - it sounds like all you need is `class_profile.tests`.

Comment: I want to query it from `TestProfile`. How can I do that?

Comment: I have edited the question now.

Comment: I don't understand your data model at all. You have `Test` associated many to one to `ClassProfile`?

Comment: Yes. `Test` can have many `ClassProfiles`, just like same test to different sections of same class or grade in school. `TestProfile` is like subjects. So a test can have many subjects. Similarly a `ClassProfile` can have many `TestProfiles`. This is how my data model should be. If there is anything wrong with my data model in the question, please tell me.

Comment: You have a typo somewhere - `has_many :tests_profiles` but `class TestProfile`. Note difference between `test` and `tests`, it should be the same for both cases

Comment: Yeah. I got it. It was a typo in the question. Changed it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `has_many through` here:

```
class Test
    has_many :tests_profiles
    has_many :class_profiles, through: :tests_profiles

class TestsProfile
    belongs_to :class_profile
    belongs_to :test

class ClassProfile
    has_many :tests_profiles
    has_many :tests, through: :tests_profiles
```

and use `class_profile.tests.each do` in the view